# Serving Compressed Assets in Heroku with Rack-Zippy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, compression, rack

I followed this tutorial on how to compress assets in Heroku.

http://www.cheynewallace.com/serving-compressed-assets-with-heroku-rack-zippy/

Here is my Application.rb file

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module Blog
  class Application < Rails::Application

    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
    config.exceptions_app = self.routes

    config.cache_store = :memory_store
    Rails.application.config.middleware.swap(ActionDispatch::Static, 
    Rack::Zippy::AssetServer, Rails.public_path)

  end
end
```

My Gem File

```
gem 'yui-compressor', '~> 0.12.0'
gem 'rack-zippy'
```

I ran heroku run rake middleware and got eh following output

```
use Rack::Sendfile
use Rack::Zippy:AssetServer
```

Now when I go to Developer Tools and the Network Tab, I see that the size is nearly identical to the content for every asset. Which means the assets were not compressed.

The only similar question I could find was this one

[rack-zippy and option -d in production env doesn't serve static assets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21629333/rack-zippy-and-option-d-in-production-env-doesnt-serve-static-assets)

And the answer didn't work.

Should I use another Compressor, because it looks like Rack Zippy does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem. Things started to work when I set `config.assets.compile` to false on `config/environments/production.rb`.

In addition is necessary pre-compile the assets before deploy.