# How i can minify the HTML output in ruby on rails?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, optimization, haml, minify

I have a ruby on rails app, and i'm using HAML for HTML structure,

I'd like to minify/uglify the output "html", remove unnecessary whitespaces and new lines.

Something like this:

```
<div class='wrapper v2-header-wrapper' id='fix-content'><div class='header header-search' style='text-align: center !important;'><nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded navbar-expand-lg'><button class='navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right' onclick='openNav()' type='button'><span class='navbar-toggler-icon'><i class='fa fa-bars'></i></span></button><a class='navbar-brand mobile pull-left' href='/'><i class='fa fa-search'></i>
```

Instead of this:

```
<div class='wrapper v2-header-wrapper' id='fix-content'>
<div class='header header-search' style='text-align: center !important;'>
<nav class='navbar navbar-toggleable-md navbar-light bg-faded navbar-expand- 
lg'>
<button class='navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right' onclick='openNav()' 
type='button'>
<span class='navbar-toggler-icon'>
<i class='fa fa-bars'></i>
</span>
</button>
<a class='navbar-brand mobile pull-left' href='/'>
<i class='fa fa-search'></i>
```

Your help is highly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about minifying your HTML. If you are trying to optimize the loading of your page I'd look elsewhere.

Comment: I think what you want is a compression for responses. Have a look here Simon F:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/25576573/1625253

Comment: @SimonFranzen I actually tried that answer but that's not what i'm looking for.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand the "why"

Comment: The linked answer explains how to compress, not how to minify html.

Comment: I'm also looking for a html minifier since I want to reduce the size of my compiled static html pages before gzipping them. There's https://code.google.com/archive/p/htmlcompressor/ but no actively maintained ruby bindings exist for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a go at this:

## `app/middleware/html_minifier.rb`

```
class HtmlMinifier
  def initialize(app)
    @app = app
  end

  def call(env)

    # Call the underlying application, return a standard Rack response
    status, headers, response = @app.call(env)

    # Make sure we don't process CSS or JavaScript
    if headers["Content-Type"] =~ /text\/html/
      response.each do |chunk|
        [
          # Join lines
          [/[\r\n]+/, ""],

          # Remove whitespace between tags
          [/>\s+</, "><"],

          # Remove comments
          [/<!--(.|\s)*?-->/, ""],

          # Remove whitespace in inline JavaScript
          [/;\s+/, ";"],
          [/{\s+/, "{"]
        ].each do |regex, substitute|
          chunk.gsub! regex, substitute
        end
      end
    end

    # Return the new Rack response
    [status, headers, response]
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a Gem for that. Just add this to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'htmlcompressor', '~> 0.4.0'
```

And this to your `application.rb`:

```
config.middleware.use HtmlCompressor::Rack
```

I'm using that within a Rails 6 application and it worked out of the box.
I would also recommend to enable GZip compression. You can do that with this middleware:

```
config.middleware.use Rack::Deflater
```

No external Gem needed for the last middleware.